# Resizing image on upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a Rails app which uses Paperclip for uploading images. The images that get uploaded have many sizes, but I want to resize them all to a width of 800px and a variable height keeping the original ratio.

I added this to the model:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, styles: { regular: '800x' }
```

But when I download the image after uploading, it has the original size.
So how kan I resize the image on upload?

Comment: This is what you need using JS.. I think it is a good start for you. try to embed it in your ruby code. https://codepen.io/dsalvagni/pen/BLapab

Comment: Hmm, resizing on the client side, never thought of that, interesting!